# How to send data from dialog back to parent container with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, state, react-props

I have a [react-big-calendar](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html) (The parent container), I have also a select which, the events of the calendar are fetched according to this select ( doctor name ) and I have a button when I click on it, the dialog will be appears (another component), on this dialog, I have a form to add an event after the select, when I post my API, I save it on local storage, but the event added doesn't appears on my calendar just after refresh the page and reselect the doctor name.
But I want, when I click on the save button, will be added directly on the calendar and it will be appeared on the calendar.

My code of **calendar** is :

```
   import Popup from './Popup';
export default class Calendar extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      events : [],
      open: false,
}}
componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND_YET+'get_liste_praticien.php')
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState ({ praticiens : data })
        localStorage.setItem('Liste de praticiens ', JSON.stringify(this.state.praticiens))
    })
}
fetchData = (nom,identifiant_user) => {
    this.setState({
      events: [],
      evtStorage:[],
      prevEvents:[], 
      evtBackend:[]
    })
      fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND+'get_liste_planning')
        .then(Response => Response.json())
        .then(data => {
          let evts = data.ListeResult;
          for (let i = 0; i < evts.length; i++) {
            evts[i].start = moment(evts[i].start).toDate();
            evts[i].end = moment(evts[i].end).toDate();
           if(evts[i].typeplanning === '0') this.setState({isConges:true})
            this.state.events.push(evts[i])
          }                   
          this.setState({
            evtBackend: evts,
            events:  evts
          })
          localStorage.setItem("Liste de planning de " + nom, JSON.stringify(this.state.events));
        }) 
        const evtCached1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Liste récente de planning de ' + nom));
        if(evtCached1 !== null) {
          for (let j = 0; j < evtCached1.length; j++) {
            evtCached1[j].start = moment(evtCached1[j].start).toDate();
            evtCached1[j].end = moment(evtCached1[j].end).toDate();
            if(evtCached1[j].typeplanning === '0') this.setState({isConges:true})
            this.state.events.push(evtCached1[j]);
          } 
          this.setState({
            events:this.state.events,
          });
          localStorage.removeItem("Liste de planning de " + nom);
        }}
// For the select
handlePraticienChange = id_user => {
    this.setState({ 
      openPopupAjout: true,
      id_user: id_user 
    },() => {
      this.state.praticiens.map((praticien)=> {
          if(this.state.id_user === praticien.id_user){
            this.setState ({ nom_user: praticien.nom_user})
           this.fetchData(praticien.nom_user, praticien.identifiant_user);
          }
      })
      }
    );
  }
// for the popup
 ModalAjoutb = (ref) => {
    if (ref) {
      this.ajoutb = ref.handleAjouterb;
    } else {
      this.ajoutb = null;
    }
  }
render() {

    return (
<div>
    <button className="bp3-button bp3-icon-add-to-artifact .bp3-fill" tabIndex="0" onClick={() => this.ajoutb(this.state.id_user, this.state.events)}>Add event</button>
    <Select  onChange={this.handlePraticienChange} value={this.state.id_user}>
        {this.state.praticiens.map((praticien) =>
            <Option key={praticien.id_user} value={praticien.id_user}>{praticien.nom_user}</Option>
        )}
    </Select>
    <DragAndDropCalendar
        selectable
        localizer={localizer}
        events={this.state.events} 
        views={['month','week','day']}
        defaultView="week"
        culture = 'fr'
    />
    <Popup ref={this.ModalAjoutb} id_user={this.state.id_user} events={this.state.events} />
</div>
);
}}
```

---

My code of **dialog** is :

```
export default class Popup extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      events : [],
}}
handleAjouterb = (id_user) => {
    this.setState({
      openPopupAjout: true,
      id_user,
    }, () => {
        this.fetchingPopup(this.state.id_user, this.state.identifiant_user, this.state.nom_user)
    });
  }
fetchingPopup = (id_user, identifiant_user, nom_user) =>{
    const praticiensCached = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Liste de praticiens '));
    for (let j = 0; j < praticiensCached.length; j++) {
      if(id_user === praticiensCached[j].id_user){
        identifiant_user = praticiensCached[j].identifiant_user;
        this.setState ({ nom_user: praticiensCached[j].nom_user })
    }
}
handleValider = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const praticiensCached = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Liste de praticiens '));
    for (let j = 0; j < praticiensCached.length; j++) {
      if(this.state.id_user === praticiensCached[j].id_user)
        this.state.identifiant_user = praticiensCached[j].identifiant_user;
    }

      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('identifiant_user', this.state.identifiant_user);
      formData.append('heuredebut', this.state.tranchesC[0].startC);
      formData.append('heurefin', this.state.tranchesC[0].endC);
      formData.append('libelleconge', this.state.libelle);
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND+'add_event_docteur',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND+'get_liste_planning/start='+moment().startOf('isoweek').subtract(14,'days').toJSON()+'&end='+moment().endOf('isoweek').add(2,'months').toJSON()+'&identifiant_user='+this.state.identifiant_user)
          .then(Response => Response.json())
          .then(data => {
            let evts = data.ListeResult;
            for (let i = 0; i < evts.length; i++) {
              evts[i].start = moment(evts[i].start).toDate();
              evts[i].end = moment(evts[i].end).toDate();
              this.state.events.push(evts[i])
            }                   
            this.setState({
              events:  this.state.events
            }, ()=> {
              localStorage.setItem('Liste récente de planning de ' + this.state.nom_user, JSON.stringify(this.state.events));
              localStorage.removeItem("Liste de planning de " + this.state.nom_user);
              localStorage.setItem("Liste de planning de " + this.state.nom_user, JSON.stringify(this.state.events));
            })
          })
       })
}

render() {

    return (
<div>
    <Dialog
        icon="application"
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        title="Organisation des plannings du docteur"
        {...this.state}
        isOpen={this.state.openPopupAjout}>
           <Input id="libelle" style={{ width: '480px' }} value={this.state.libelle} onChange={this.handleInputChange('libelle')}/>       
            <label className="pt-label .modifier"><strong>Date</strong></label>
            <LocaleProvider locale={fr_FR}>
                <RangePicker id="date" name= "date"  locale="fr" placeholder={["Date de début","Date de fin"]} separator="-" onChange={this.handleDateCChange}
                    value={this.state.dateIC} format="DD/MM/YYYY" allowClear={false}/> 
            </LocaleProvider>
            <label className="pt-label .modifier"> <strong>Heure de début</strong></label>
            <Time value={el.startC} onChange={time => this.handleKeyboardStartCChange(i, time)} style={heure} disableUnderline={true} inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
                    endAdornment={ <InputAdornment position="end" style={{opacity:'0.4'}}> <IconButton   onClick={() => this.openDialogC(i, el.startC, "startC")}><i  style={{fontSize:'18px'}} className="zmdi zmdi-alarm" /></IconButton>  </InputAdornment>}
            />
            <label className="pt-label .modifier"> <strong>Heure de fin</strong></label>
            <Time value={el.endC} onChange={time => this.handleKeyboardEndCChange(i, time)} style={heure} disableUnderline={true} inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
                    endAdornment={ <InputAdornment position="end" style={{opacity:'0.4'}}> <IconButton  onClick={() => this.openDialogC(i, el.endC, "endC")}><i  style={{fontSize:'18px'}} className="zmdi zmdi-alarm" /></IconButton></InputAdornment> }/>

            <Clock maxWidth="xs" open={this.state.isOpenC} onBackdropClick={this.closeDialogC}>
            <TimePicker  mode="24h" value={this.createDateFromTextValueC(this.state.datePickerValueC)} onChange={this.handleDialogCChange}/>
            <DialogActions> <ButtonOk onClick={this.closeDialogC} color="primary"> Ok </ButtonOk></DialogActions>
            </Clock>
                <AnchorButton style={{display:'inline-block'}} intent={Intent.SUCCESS} onClick={this.handleValider}>Valider</AnchorButton>

</div>
);
}}
```

---

I want to refresh the list of my events and appear my  event added on the calendar afer post form on the popup and not after the  refresh of the page and I will reselect the doctor.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Add localStorage to state, then send state via props!

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina  Can you give me how to code it  please?

Comment: I added a pseudo code

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina check my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't save events in your state, in Popup access the events directly from props.

In your Calendar, create a function that'll update the state.

```
updateEvents = (events, callback = () => {}) => {
  this.setState(
    {
      events
    },
    callback
  );
};

<Popup updateEvents={this.updateEvents} ref={this.ModalAjoutb} id_user={this.state.id_user} events={this.state.events} />
```

Popup

```
export default class Popup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleAjouterb = id_user => {
    this.setState(
      {
        openPopupAjout: true,
        id_user
      },
      () => {
        this.fetchingPopup(
          this.state.id_user,
          this.state.identifiant_user,
          this.state.nom_user
        );
      }
    );
  };
  fetchingPopup = (id_user, identifiant_user, nom_user) => {
    const praticiensCached = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('Liste de praticiens ')
    );
    for (let j = 0; j < praticiensCached.length; j++) {
      if (id_user === praticiensCached[j].id_user) {
        identifiant_user = praticiensCached[j].identifiant_user;
        this.setState({ nom_user: praticiensCached[j].nom_user });
      }
    }
    handleValider = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const praticiensCached = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem('Liste de praticiens ')
      );
      for (let j = 0; j < praticiensCached.length; j++) {
        if (this.state.id_user === praticiensCached[j].id_user)
          this.state.identifiant_user = praticiensCached[j].identifiant_user;
      }

      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('identifiant_user', this.state.identifiant_user);
      formData.append('heuredebut', this.state.tranchesC[0].startC);
      formData.append('heurefin', this.state.tranchesC[0].endC);
      formData.append('libelleconge', this.state.libelle);
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND + 'add_event_docteur',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(() => {
        fetch(
          process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND +
            'get_liste_planning/start=' +
            moment()
              .startOf('isoweek')
              .subtract(14, 'days')
              .toJSON() +
            '&end=' +
            moment()
              .endOf('isoweek')
              .add(2, 'months')
              .toJSON() +
            '&identifiant_user=' +
            this.state.identifiant_user
        )
          .then(Response => Response.json())
          .then(data => {
            let evts = data.ListeResult;
            for (let i = 0; i < evts.length; i++) {
              evts[i].start = moment(evts[i].start).toDate();
              evts[i].end = moment(evts[i].end).toDate();
            }
            this.props.updateEvents(evts, () => {
              localStorage.setItem(
                'Liste récente de planning de ' + this.state.nom_user,
                JSON.stringify(evts)
              );
              localStorage.removeItem(
                'Liste de planning de ' + this.state.nom_user
              );
              localStorage.setItem(
                'Liste de planning de ' + this.state.nom_user,
                JSON.stringify(evts)
              );
            });
          });
      });
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          icon="application"
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          title="Organisation des plannings du docteur"
          {...this.state}
          isOpen={this.state.openPopupAjout}
        >
          <Input
            id="libelle"
            style={{ width: '480px' }}
            value={this.state.libelle}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange('libelle')}
          />
          <label className="pt-label .modifier">
            <strong>Date</strong>
          </label>
          <LocaleProvider locale={fr_FR}>
            <RangePicker
              id="date"
              name="date"
              locale="fr"
              placeholder={['Date de début', 'Date de fin']}
              separator="-"
              onChange={this.handleDateCChange}
              value={this.state.dateIC}
              format="DD/MM/YYYY"
              allowClear={false}
            />
          </LocaleProvider>
          <label className="pt-label .modifier">
            {' '}
            <strong>Heure de début</strong>
          </label>
          <Time
            value={el.startC}
            onChange={time => this.handleKeyboardStartCChange(i, time)}
            style={heure}
            disableUnderline={true}
            inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end" style={{ opacity: '0.4' }}>
                {' '}
                <IconButton
                  onClick={() => this.openDialogC(i, el.startC, 'startC')}
                >
                  <i style={{ fontSize: '18px' }} className="zmdi zmdi-alarm" />
                </IconButton>{' '}
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
          <label className="pt-label .modifier">
            {' '}
            <strong>Heure de fin</strong>
          </label>
          <Time
            value={el.endC}
            onChange={time => this.handleKeyboardEndCChange(i, time)}
            style={heure}
            disableUnderline={true}
            inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end" style={{ opacity: '0.4' }}>
                {' '}
                <IconButton
                  onClick={() => this.openDialogC(i, el.endC, 'endC')}
                >
                  <i style={{ fontSize: '18px' }} className="zmdi zmdi-alarm" />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
          <Clock
            maxWidth="xs"
            open={this.state.isOpenC}
            onBackdropClick={this.closeDialogC}
          >
            <TimePicker
              mode="24h"
              value={this.createDateFromTextValueC(this.state.datePickerValueC)}
              onChange={this.handleDialogCChange}
            />
            <DialogActions>
              {' '}
              <ButtonOk onClick={this.closeDialogC} color="primary">
                {' '}
                Ok{' '}
              </ButtonOk>
            </DialogActions>
          </Clock>
          <AnchorButton
            style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
            intent={Intent.SUCCESS}
            onClick={this.handleValider}
          >
            Valider
          </AnchorButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, you can achieve it using code like this:

```
export default ComponentA extends Component {
  // set localStorage to bar state value
  // via click or whatever ...
    foo () {
    this.setState({
      bar: localStorage.getItem('bar')
    })
  }

  render () {
    // send the value of state to ComponentB
    return <ComponentB foo={this.state.bar}>
  }
}
```

Into your component

```
export default class ComponentB extends Component {
    render () {
    // display the value of foo prop
    return <div>{this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}
```

**Note:** You can always try to get the content of your `localStorage`directly from the `ComponentB`(Maybe using ComponentDidUpdate???) but the way I show you is better.

Comment: I try `foo (nom) {
    this.setState({
      events: localStorage.getItem('Liste récente de planning de ' + nom)
    })}` but it doesn't working, it 's the same issue.

Comment: and how you call your foo?

Comment: I call my foo on the Popup Component like as : `this.state = { events: this.props.foo }`

Comment: It's a bad practice to set state like this. you should use `setState` ... 
Within your popup code, just call `this.foo('your name')`

Comment: I get `TypeError: _this.props.foo is not a function`

Comment: it's not `this.props.foo()` but only `this.foo()`

Comment: It must add it after the response of axios on the Popup component ?

Comment: I try `ComponentDidUpdate` but it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why not you use context Feature of React 
[React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

### context.js

```
export const store = {
  something: 'val',
  setSomeThing : () => {}
};

export const CalContext = React.createContext(
  store // default value
);
```

### pop-up.js

```
import {CalContext} from './context';

class Popup extends React.Component {

   updateValue = () => {
     this.context.setSomeThing('new_value');
   }    

   render() {
    let calContext = this.context;

    return (
      <button onClick={this.updateValue} >
        {calContext.something}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

Popup.contextType = CalContext;

export default Popup;
```

### calender.js

```
import {CalContext} from './context';
import Popup from './pop-up'

class calender extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         something : 'value'
      }
   }

  setSomeThing = (newVal) => {
    // actual set something code.
    this.setState({something : newVal});
  }

render() {
let contextVal = { something : this.state.something, setSomeThing : this.setSomeThing }
// The entire state is passed to the provider
return (
  <CalContext.Provider value={contextVal}>
    <Popup />
  </CalContext.Provider>
   );}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this

```
class ComponentB extends React.Component{
  render(){
    this.props.setInLocalStorage();
    const value = localStorage.getItem("testA");
    return <div>
  This is componentB{value}
  </div>}
}
class ComponentA extends React.Component{
 setInLocalStorage = ()=>{
   localStorage.setItem('testA', 'Hello');
}
render(){
  return <ComponentB setInLocalStorage={this.setInLocalStorage}/>
}
}
```

Comment: but I want after I add the event from the popup, it will be appears on my calendar directly, not after refresh the page and reselect the doctor

Answer (score 1):

You can either use React Context API or Redux.

But if you don't want those, you can use a prop that is a method in your child component, so the parent can capture the event. It is similar Output mechanic from Angular 2+.

Here is an example:

```
const ChildComponent = (onSelect = () => {}) => {
  return <div onClick={() => onSelect('You selected me')}>Child Component</div>
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return <ChildComponent onSelect={message => console.log(message)} /> // You selected me
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your parent component i.e `<Calendar/>` you can a define a method for say

```
HandleNewDataFromPopup(data) {
   this.setState({newData: data})
}
```

and pass this method as a prop in the Popup component

```
<Popup HandleNewDataFromPopup={this.HandleNewDataFromPopup}/>
```

and in your `<Popup/>` component in the method `handleValider` on sucess of fetch call you can call the method HandleNewDataFromPopup `(this.props.HandleNewDataFromPopup)` to populate the data in your parent component

```
handleValider() {
  // on axios success
  this.props.HandleNewDataFromPopup(data)
}
```

Does this answer your question?