# How to render a checkbox with text inside using Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, checkbox, antd

I have an [ant-design checkbox](https://ant.design/components/checkbox/)

My code is :

```
 <Checkbox  checked={this.state.D} onChange={(e)=> this.setState({ D: e.target.checked})}>D</Checkbox>
 <Checkbox  checked={this.state.L} onChange={(e)=> this.setState({ L: e.target.checked})}>L</Checkbox>
 <Checkbox  checked={this.state.M} onChange={(e)=> this.setState({ M: e.target.checked})}>M</Checkbox>
 <Checkbox  checked={this.state.M1} onChange={(e)=> this.setState({ M1: e.target.checked})}>M</Checkbox>
 <Checkbox  checked={this.state.J} onChange={(e)=> this.setState({ J: e.target.checked})}>J</Checkbox>
```

when I run it, I get :

[image]

But, I want it with text inside like that:

[image]

How can I render it ?

Comment: This is a place where you show code that doesn't work the way you want, and we help you fix it.  So please add some code.

Comment: @Seano666 I added my code, can you check it please ?

Comment: So what does it look like now, and what have you tried to implement the design?

Comment: @Seano666 check my post please, I edit it.

Comment: How much google searching have you done, I quickly found an example  https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/WjZVjo

Comment: @Seano666 it doesn't working with the checkbox of antd

Comment: His question is fair, you should not downvote here, he asks about antd design, where it's pretty hard to style given component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding text inside of `Checkbox` in `antd` is equivalent to [Radio.Group](https://ant.design/components/radio/#RadioGroup).

```js
<Radio.Group defaultValue="a" size="large">
  <Radio.Button value="a">Hangzhou</Radio.Button>
  <Radio.Button value="b">Shanghai</Radio.Button>
  <Radio.Button value="c">Beijing</Radio.Button>
  <Radio.Button value="d">Chengdu</Radio.Button>
</Radio.Group>;
```

[image: Radio Group]

If you want to use "Round Buttons" as in your example, you should make your own component using `<Button shape="circle"/>` and manage it's clicked state.

[image]

> Note: how to make such component is out of the scope of this question, although it is pretty basic.

Demo:

[image: Edit OS-Q-56528776]

Comment: For multi-selection, you need `Button.Group` https://ant.design/components/button/

Comment: Thank you @Dennis can you help me on this please ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337582/how-to-send-data-from-dialog-back-to-parent-container-with-react

Comment: Sure thing I'll check it out